# Is there anyway to add many objects inside an object variable that is constructed just with object?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I want to add more than one object inside a variable contructed just with object. Language (Javascript). 
Example: var x = {"a": {}, "b": {"name": "Hello World"}};

I'm trying to add more than one object for the x.a, but when i add more than one in x.a and when i request some value of these objcts that i've added to x.a, the console back undefined. i would like to know if i can add more than one objects without using array.

```
var x = {"a": {}, "b": {"name": "Hello World"}};
x.a = {"name": "Paradox"};
x.a += {"first", "Hello"};
x.a += Object.assign({"second", "World"});
console.log(x.a.first);// Returns undefined
```

When put console.log(x.a.first) it returns undefined. I know that using array i would get the results i want that is "Hello". But i would like to know if i can add many objects and get the same results without using array.

Comment: This would also not work with an array.

Comment: What i would do to solve this problem? Do you have any idea? If i add like this: x.a[0] = {"name": "Paradox"}; x.a[1] = {"first": "Hello"}; it works for me.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your choice of syntax; writing x.a.first = "Hello" would work. I'm also not certain what you're trying to do with Object.assign. I'd recommend checking out the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign.

Comment: Any chance you can show us what the resulting object you're trying to get looksl ike in json? There's several interactive editors you can use if you're new to js. ie. https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: results that i want: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d7abd06382ae485cbfe3442edafebf2e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current logic wont work because `+=` is used for concatenation, you can't concatenate objects, or even arrays like that.

There's many options you can use to do what you want, I'll show you two of them:

**First**: Using `x.a` as an object (that you already have), you can create a key on the run and assing a value to it, then accessing x.a["keyName"] will return the value, for example: `x.a["first"]` will return "Hello".

```js
var x = {
  "a": {},
  "b": {
    "name": "Hello World"
  }
};

x.a["name"] = "Paradox";
x.a["first"] = "Hello";

console.log(x.a)
console.log(x.a.first);
```

**Second**: Using `x.a` as an array of objects. You create an object with key/value and insert into this array, but, to find a value, you'll need to iterate over the array, there's many ways to do that, here I'm using `find()`, check the code for better understanding.

```js
var x = {
  "a": [],
  "b": {
    "name": "Hello World"
  }
};

x.a.push({"name": "Paradox"});
x.a.push({"first": "Hello"});

console.log(x.a.find(y => y["first"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Each key in a JavaScript object, can only be mapped to one value. That value may be the key for another value, depending on what type it is.

You could have an array inside x.a, ex:

```
x.a = [ {"name": "Paradox"}, {"first": "Hello"}, {"second": "World"} ]
```

in which case you would access each individual object like so:

> x.a[0].name  --> "Paradox"
>   x.a[1].first --> "Hello"

OR you could add more properties to the x.a object mostly in two ways:

1.
`x.a = {
    ...x.a,
    "first": "Hello",
    "second": "World"
}`

2.`x.a = Object.assign(x.a, {"first": "Hello", "second": "World"})`

It would be best if you avoided mutating an object directly, try to construct a new one each time. That includes `x` object as well.